# How can I access a val from a data class in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

So I want to access `isInBounds`

Navigation.kt:

```
data class Coordinate(val x:Int , val y:Int){

    val isInBounds = x >= 0 && y >= 0

    operator fun plus(other:Coordinate) = Coordinate(x + other.x, y + other.y)

}
```

But when I try to access it I get an unresolved reference.

Game.kt

```
private fun move(directionInput: String) = try {
    val direction = Direction.valueOf(directionInput.uppercase())
    val newPosition = direction.updateCoordinate(player.currentPosition)


    

    if (!newPosition.isInBounds){

    }
    else{

    }
} catch (e: Exception){

}
```

```
enum class Direction(private val  coordinate: Coordinate){
    NORTH(Coordinate(0 , -1)),     
    EAST(Coordinate(1 , 0)),     
    SOUTH(Coordinate(0 , 1)),     
    WEST(Coordinate(-1 , 0));      
    fun updateCoordinate(playerCoordinate:Coordinate) {         
        coordinate + playerCoordinate     
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does `direction.updateCoordinate()` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in `Direction`. Note that you did not specify a return type for `updateCoordinate`, *and* you used a block body for it. This means that it implicitly returns `Unit`. So `updateCoordinate` calculates `coordinate + playerCoordinate`, discards the result, and returns `Unit`. This causes `newPosition` to be `Unit`, and that is obviously not going to be have an `isInBounds` property.

Clearly that is not what you want. You should instead declare `updateCoordinate` with an expression body:

```
fun updateCoordinate(playerCoordinate:Coordinate) =
    coordinate + playerCoordinate
```

or if you like block bodies:

```
fun updateCoordinate(playerCoordinate:Coordinate): Coordinate {
    return coordinate + playerCoordinate
}
```

---

This is just my opinion, but I think it is more readable to have `updateCoordinate` as a method on `Coordinate`, called `movedTowards`:

```
data class Coordinate(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    operator fun plus(coord: Coordinate) = ...

    fun movedTowards(direction: Direction) =
        this + direction.coordinate // you'd have to make direction.coordinate public
}
```

Comment: A suggestion: In the standard library, functions that mutate an object have the present-indicative verb form, and functions that return a modified copy of an object have the past-participle verb form. So a more conventional name in this case would be "movedTowards".

Answer (score 1):

Your `updateCoordinate` function doesn't actually accomplish anything because it calculates something without doing anything with the result, like returning it. Therefore, it implicitly returns Unit, so `newPosition` is just a reference to Unit.

Change the function to return the new coordinate:

```
fun updateCoordinate(playerCoordinate: Coordinate): Coordinate {         
    return coordinate + playerCoordinate     
}
```

I recommend giving this function a better name. The word "update" implies that it is mutating the instance that is passed to it instead of calculating a new one.

Logically, since this function is something that adds something to a coordinate, it would make more sense for legibility and easy reasoning of your code to invert it (swap the receiver and parameter). So I would pull this function out of the enum class and make it a Coordinate extension function.

```
fun Coordinate.moved(direction: Direction): Coordinate {
    return this + direction.coordinate
}
```

but you'll have to make the Direction's `coordinate` property public or `internal`.